# Lag function in pyspark is not functioning correctly

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, window

df is a dataframe without any unique identifier.
I have to use a lag function on a column to calculate its previous values
code is as shown below

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
 import pyspark.sql.functions as func
df = df1.withColumn('id', monotonically_increasing_id())
df.select('id').show()
window = Window.orderBy("id")
df = df1.withColumn('price_close',(func.lag(col("price_open"), 1).over(window)))\
```

I receive an error stating "AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`id`' "
df.select('id').show() -->outputs

```
         0|
| 8589934592|
| 8589934593|
|17179869184|
|17179869185|
|25769803776|
|25769803777|
|34359738368
```

what is wrong with the code

Answer (score 2):

Id column is in df not df1

Replace last line with  since your window contains reference to id

```
df = df.withColumn('price_close',(func.lag(col("price_open"), 1).over(window)))
```